# How can detect if two item select on same time from two different recyclerview adapter of two fragment?

Tags: java, android, model, android-recyclerview

My project include two different `model` that using in `recyclerview`. `Bus.java` and `Voyage.java`. This model get data from `api`. `BusAdapter.java` and `VoyageAdapter.java` these adapters load this data to `layout`. These `adapter` in same `Activity`. I want to detect if user click one of item from `BusAdapter.java` after it click `VoyageAdapter.java`. How can I detect it?

I've already tried create one `interface` class and make same variable for use and get `URL` tag of these two model. But I can't compare these two different model if they have same tag or not.

I can detect here if user choose different voyage type from `Voyage.java` model in the `Cart.java`. I need to do same for `Bus.java` and `Voyage.java`.

```
public class Cart {
    public float totalPrice = 0;
    public ArrayList<Bus> buses = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<Voyage> voyages = new ArrayList<>(); // SATIN AL'A 
    public ArrayList<Hotel> hotels = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<RentingCar> rentingCars = new ArrayList<>();

    public CartStateResult ifValidAddToCart(Voyage voyage) {
        CartStateResult result = new CartStateResult();


        boolean cartContainsDifferentTypeVoyage(final String type_voyage) {
        ArrayList<Voyage> list = Lists.newArrayList(Collections2.filter(voyages, new Predicate<Voyage>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(Voyage voyage) {
                return !voyage.getType_voyage().equals(type_voyage);
            }
        }));
        return list.size() > 0 ? true : false;
    }
```

Comment: You could make both fragments communicate back to the Activity what the current selection is and then compare the two there. Alternatively you can use EventBus (search on github) to either broadcast when a selection is made or keep it stored by marking it sticky so that you can compare in a second Activity or other fragment depending on the use case.

Comment: @cYrixmorten Ok. Thank you for answer. I will search that.